# exit from while loop

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, infinite-loop

Here i am having function like this. problem i am facing while changing Set parameter section. 
first: i could not able to change Set_parameter Window
Second: Since in my loop i am saying if none key pressed display clock.because of that when i enter into Section menu it directly bounce back to Main displaying clock. Is there any way, where i can stay menu section unless Exit/LEFT key pressed

This main function where i am calling my LCD_call Function

```
 void loop()
    {
     int button;
     while(( button = read_LCD_buttons()) != btnNONE)
     {
     lcd_call();digitalClockDisplay();
     }
    }
```

LCD_call being called here.
[LCD_call](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7031290/)

Comment: Is not `break`enough? From what line do you want to leave?

Comment: what o/p you needed ?

Comment: `break` is normally used to exit from a loop other then its normal exit condition.

Comment: or you can create boolean variabel example `bool bExit = false` , `while(!bExit)` and then after user click button `bExit = true`

Comment: In your example the break is not even needed. The if clause evaluates the same condition as the while loop, so it will break in both cases at the same time and the if clause is not needed here.

Comment: i wanted to condition to made false. If while(button!=btnSELECT) initially true so keep executing. i am using multiple break because in order to check previous state of counter.In 2 ways condition became false either counter >5 or key pressed is equal to btnselect. But it not even exit.here how can made while loop false

Comment: If `button == btnSELECT` the break statement will be executed and your code will leave the while loop, so where is the problem ? But in your case the `if (button == btnSELECT)` is not even necessary because your while loop will be terminated as soon as `(button == btnSELECT)` because `(button == btnSELECT)` is tested in the `while`statement.

Answer (score 1):

`break` command should break/exit the loop. 
It could be that the `if` condition is not coming out to be true, for any input case.

Try debugging your code by placing a break point inside `if`.

`if(button==btnSELECT)
    {
     break; // place your breakpoint here.
    }`

and check if your code satifies the `if` condition for any possible input.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
void lcd_call()
{
    while ( (button = read_LCD_buttons()) != btnSELECT)
    {
        DS_Counter=Display_selection();

        switch (DS_Counter)
        {
            case 1:
                lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                digitalClockDisplay();
                timedBeep(shortBeep,1);
                break;
            case 2:
                lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                Display_angle();
                timedBeep(shortBeep,1);
                break;
            case 3:
                lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                Display_coordinate();
                timedBeep(shortBeep,1);
                break;
            case 4:
                lcd.setCursor(0,0);
                Display_Wind();
                timedBeep(shortBeep,1);
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `read_LCD_buttons()` ever returns btnSELECT ? If not, then it's normal that your loop never stops. Check your `read_LCD_buttons()` function, I'm sure the  problem is there.

Comment: Similar thing i wanted to do with Setting parameter. Once parameter being set it should go to case2 : then case3 : @ end exit loop

Answer (score 0):

You have already given a condition in While loop. As soon as the condition is false, it will break the while loop